Expected card draws until two consecutive aces $\mathbf{with\, replacement}$
Im trying to find the expected draws until there are two consecutive aces with replacement, using this formula:
$E(X) = 13 + \frac{1}{13}+\frac{12}{13}(E(X)+1)\\E(X) = 13\times 14=182$
Is this the right way to approach it? Any help would be appreciated!

Don't yell, please.

@ArturoMagidin The posted question was easier for me to understand, specifically because the phrase "with replacement" was highlighted.

@user2661923 and one can "highlight" without yelling.

Thanks for the help cheers, also didnt know the bold character was that obvious lol, though it does make a big difference in the answering

Since there is replacement the cards of a same value are fungible.
Let $x$ be the expected value.

$x=1/13*(1/13*2+12/13*(x+2))+12/13*(x+1)$
$\rightarrow x=182$
